# Which states codes have to be used for Srilanka in Paypal?

Tags: paypal

Can i find the states codes somewhere that have to be used for the Paypal address format ?

Which states codes have to be used for Srilanka?

Answer (score 0):

When you mean the two-character country codes, that would be

> lk

Reference: https://www.paypal.com/lk/webapps/mpp/home

They are using the two-digit "alpha 2" country codes as defined in [ISO 3166](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search).